# oneko: Error and exit

Tags: ssh, x11, raspberry-pi, raspbian, xforwarding

I'm working on a Raspberry Pi Zero W running Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster). Other X11 applications like `xlogo`, `xclock`, `xosview`, and even `xeyes` works perfectly well, but I have no luck running [`oneko`](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/oneko/oneko.6).

```
pi@nalzoks-pi:~ $ oneko
Display not supported shape extension.
oneko: Error and exit.
BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
pi@nalzoks-pi:~ $ oneko -noshape
oneko: Error and exit.
BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
pi@nalzoks-pi:~ $ sudo oneko
sudo: oneko: command not found
```

I'm accessing the Pi through SSH within a local network and using X11 forwarding.

Any thought?

---

Here is more information in case you need it

#### On Pi Zero (SSH server accessed with `ssh -X pi@nalzoks-pi.local`)

```
pi@nalzoks-pi:~ $ echo $DISPLAY
nalzoks-pi:11.0
pi@nalzoks-pi:~ $ sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
autossh   1608    pi    3u  IPv4  19696      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:30001 (LISTEN)
ssh       1613    pi    4u  IPv6  19718      0t0  TCP [::1]:30000 (LISTEN)
ssh       1613    pi    5u  IPv4  19719      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:30000 (LISTEN)
sshd      1719  root    3u  IPv4  20283      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd      1719  root    4u  IPv6  20289      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd      7110    pi   10u  IPv4  38831      0t0  TCP *:6010 (LISTEN)
sshd      7110    pi   11u  IPv6  38832      0t0  TCP *:6010 (LISTEN)
sshd      7394    pi   10u  IPv4  40700      0t0  TCP *:6011 (LISTEN)
sshd      7394    pi   11u  IPv6  40701      0t0  TCP *:6011 (LISTEN)
pi@nalzoks-pi:~ $ xdpyinfo
name of display:    nalzoks-pi:11.0
version number:    11.0
vendor string:    The X.Org Foundation
vendor release number:    11804000
X.Org version: 1.18.4
maximum request size:  16777212 bytes
motion buffer size:  256
bitmap unit, bit order, padding:    32, LSBFirst, 32
image byte order:    LSBFirst
number of supported pixmap formats:    7
supported pixmap formats:
    depth 1, bits_per_pixel 1, scanline_pad 32
    depth 4, bits_per_pixel 8, scanline_pad 32
    depth 8, bits_per_pixel 8, scanline_pad 32
    depth 15, bits_per_pixel 16, scanline_pad 32
    depth 16, bits_per_pixel 16, scanline_pad 32
    depth 24, bits_per_pixel 32, scanline_pad 32
    depth 32, bits_per_pixel 32, scanline_pad 32
keycode range:    minimum 8, maximum 255
focus:  None
number of extensions:    2
    BIG-REQUESTS
    XC-MISC
default screen number:    0
number of screens:    1

screen #0:
  dimensions:    1440x878 pixels (381x232 millimeters)
  resolution:    96x96 dots per inch
  depths (7):    24, 1, 4, 8, 15, 16, 32
  root window id:    0x111
  depth of root window:    24 planes
  number of colormaps:    minimum 1, maximum 1
  default colormap:    0x21
  default number of colormap cells:    256
  preallocated pixels:    black 0, white 16777215
  options:    backing-store NO, save-unders NO
  largest cursor:    32x32
  current input event mask:    0x1a0000
    StructureNotifyMask      SubstructureNotifyMask   SubstructureRedirectMask
  number of visuals:    80
  default visual id:  0x22
  visual:
    visual id:    0x22
    class:    TrueColor
    depth:    24 planes
    available colormap entries:    256 per subfield
    red, green, blue masks:    0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff
    significant bits in color specification:    8 bits
  visual:
    visual id:    0xc1
    class:    TrueColor
    depth:    24 planes
    available colormap entries:    256 per subfield
    red, green, blue masks:    0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff
    significant bits in color specification:    8 bits

  ... similar line omitted for brevity ...
```

#### On MacBook Pro (SSH client)

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
:0
$ xdpyinfo
name of display:    :0
version number:    11.0
vendor string:    The X.Org Foundation
vendor release number:    11804000
X.Org version: 1.18.4
maximum request size:  16777212 bytes
motion buffer size:  256
bitmap unit, bit order, padding:    32, LSBFirst, 32
image byte order:    LSBFirst
number of supported pixmap formats:    7
supported pixmap formats:
    depth 1, bits_per_pixel 1, scanline_pad 32
    depth 4, bits_per_pixel 8, scanline_pad 32
    depth 8, bits_per_pixel 8, scanline_pad 32
    depth 15, bits_per_pixel 16, scanline_pad 32
    depth 16, bits_per_pixel 16, scanline_pad 32
    depth 24, bits_per_pixel 32, scanline_pad 32
    depth 32, bits_per_pixel 32, scanline_pad 32
keycode range:    minimum 8, maximum 255
focus:  None
number of extensions:    25
    Apple-DRI
    Apple-WM
    BIG-REQUESTS
    DAMAGE
    DOUBLE-BUFFER
    GLX
    Generic Event Extension
    MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
    MIT-SHM
    Present
    RANDR
    RECORD
    RENDER
    SECURITY
    SGI-GLX
    SHAPE
    SYNC
    X-Resource
    XC-MISC
    XFIXES
    XINERAMA
    XInputExtension
    XKEYBOARD
    XTEST
    XVideo
default screen number:    0
number of screens:    1

screen #0:
  dimensions:    1440x878 pixels (381x232 millimeters)
  resolution:    96x96 dots per inch
  depths (7):    24, 1, 4, 8, 15, 16, 32
  root window id:    0x111
  depth of root window:    24 planes
  number of colormaps:    minimum 1, maximum 1
  default colormap:    0x21
  default number of colormap cells:    256
  preallocated pixels:    black 0, white 16777215
  options:    backing-store NO, save-unders NO
  largest cursor:    32x32
  current input event mask:    0x1a0000
    StructureNotifyMask      SubstructureNotifyMask   SubstructureRedirectMask
  number of visuals:    80
  default visual id:  0x22
  visual:
    visual id:    0x22
    class:    TrueColor
    depth:    24 planes
    available colormap entries:    256 per subfield
    red, green, blue masks:    0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff
    significant bits in color specification:    8 bits
  visual:
    visual id:    0xc1
    class:    TrueColor
    depth:    24 planes
    available colormap entries:    256 per subfield
    red, green, blue masks:    0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff
    significant bits in color specification:    8 bits

  ... similar line omitted for brevity ...
```

Comment: I don't know any current X server that doesn't support the shape extension. Are you sure that you are running an X server (and not e.g. Wayland) on the local computer you are accessing the Pi from? `xdpyinfo` may give some more information. Can you run `oneko` on your local computer?

Comment: @dirkt Please see output of `xdpyinfo` [here](https://pastebin.com/QjqNgEDi). Unfortunately my local computer runs macOS, so there are no `oneko` (Homebrew does have a package named `neko`, but that it to https://nekovm.org).

Comment: try with `ssh -Y` instead of `ssh -X` (`ForwardX11Trusted=yes`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you login via ssh from a Mac to the Pi, the client program (oneko) runs on the Pi, and contacts the X server that is running on the Mac.

I just tried this by logging into my Debian PC from my MacBook via `ssh`, and `oneko` runs fine, and when I do `xdpyinfo`, I see the same amount of extensions as I see when I do `xdpyinfo` directly on my Mac.

However, in your case the forwarded connection is drastically different:

```
number of extensions:    2
  BIG-REQUESTS
  XC-MISC
```

and that is way to few extensions, in particular no SHAPE. So now the question is why this happens.

I see that you have two X forwarding logins (sshd listening both on 6010 and on 6011). What happens when you use only a single login?

**Edit**

To add the outcome of the comments to the answer: It is necessary to use ssh with trusted forwarding (i.e. `ssh -Y` instead of `ssh -X`) to make all the extensions available.

Comment: I have logged out of one session but still got the same errors. Is there any way to fix the too-few-extensions issue, presumably by (re)installing the X11 infrastructure?

Comment: I've no idea what's causing it; comparing the `xdpyinfo`, it seems to be the same server. Can you log out on both connections, login again and try if `xdpyinfo` now shows the full extension list? What's your MacOS version?

Comment: I have logged out of all sessions, and even did a reboot on Pi, but the X11 server on Pi still has two extensions only. I'm on the latest version of macOS Mojave.

Comment: Interesting. I had to login with `ssh -Y`, because `ssh -X` couldn't generate the `xauth` cookies for some reason, so I couldn't do it that way. Can you try that too?

Comment: THAT WORKS! The key is `-Y`, I guess.

Comment: @nalzok The source of the confusion is that Debian has turned on `ForwardX11Trusted` by default (contrary to the default from upstream ssh), and people tend to assume that that is the default everywhere, which is not. Without `ForwardX11Trusted`, most X11 extensions won't be available, and most X11 apps will be crippled, so you should either always use `ssh -Y` or if in doubt, not use X11 forwarding at all.